# Laravel jobs (database) do not execute handle

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

I have a problem with laravel jobs.
I configured laravel jobs to work with the database and it is working.

When I execute a job, the entry is created in database and the constructor is well executed.

However, the handle function is never executed ... and the jobs stay in the jobs table.

Someone already had this problem?

(I use Laravel 5.7).

Comment: Are you running the queue from the command line? For example via command "php artisan queue:work"

Comment: Yes i use the command. I tried 'php artisan queue:work' and 'php artisan queue:listen' but nothing change....

Comment: Do you have any output on the command line with queue:work ? I prefer using laravel horizon with redis, the monitoring page is good, you can try it.

Comment: No output on the command line ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem...

I'm using a different queue name that the default and in config/queue.php, in the database array you have the default queue name set to "default".

So when i execute : php artisan queue:work , he is waiting for default queue.

When i execute the command line : php artisan queue:work --queue QUEUENAME it is working !

Thanks everybody.

Comment: Great this will be very helpful, in this case

Answer (score 0):

You should listen to the queue for default

```sh
php artisan queue:work
```

or

```sh
php artisan queue:work --sleep=1 --tries=5 --timeout=60
```

If you are not using the default queue then mention the custom queue

```sh
php artisan queue:work --sleep=1 --tries=5 --timeout=60 --queue customQueue
```